# iPhone memory management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, alloc

I have been using instruments to check for leaks and other memory issues in my program. Though the leaks found by instruments are extremely small and don't matter, I have found that the physical memory free keeps going down while I use the program.

I use memory monitor to determine how much memory my app is using up and allocations to determine where this is mainly happening. I always make sure to release every time I alloc or retain, and seeing how there are barely any leaks, I'm assuming that my memory management is fine.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this issue or reccomend a way to get to the bottom of it?

Comment: ANY leak matters. "Barely" doesn't cut it, there should be none.

Comment: Agree with @MarkPowell. There should be no leaks through the entire life of the program with all functionality tested. Isolate each leak to a section of code and go through it with a fine-toothed comb if you have to, resolve it, rinse, and repeat. Once you've got all the leaks plugged you can reevaluate to see if there are other problems that need addressing, but you must start with the leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even tho you release objects you dont need, that doesn't matter. You are probably allocating too much things and keeping them for some reason. You can try to check this out:

http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-memory-management.html

http://akosma.com/2009/01/28/10-iphone-memory-management-tips/

I would advise you to check what you alloc and what you keep for the life of the application and see if you can make the same thing but without using so much memory.

Edit: I have to agree with Mark and Kongress, every leak matters for the sake of your app's life.

Comment: So I have managed to improve the memory by quite a bit (though its still not completely perfect). I have found that the two main issues I was having was not releasing pointers which had a retain property, and that I was using UIImage imageNamed everywhere (and I have hundreds of images) which cached all the images.

Comment: If you need more help, just let me know Olshansk.